# Change Bound Property in OnPost in model is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I am using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages and I want to add a counter for a number of attempts it takes a user complete a task.

I am using:

```
[BindProperty]
public int Attempts { get; set; }
```

And inside the `OnPost` I am doing this:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
   if(!IsCorrect())
   {
       Attempts++;
       return Page();
   }

   return RedirectToPage($"./Index")
}
```

I expected this to update the data on the client side, since without `[BindProperty]` & `return Page()`, data would be lost if the model was invalid. However, `Attempts` never increases on the client.

I think I may have misunderstood how this works? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once your `OnPost` method completes and the corresponding View is rendered, the values that are displayed in controls that use the `asp-for` Tag Helper (or the older `HtmlHelper` methods) are repopulated from `ModelState`. This means that even though you are setting a new value for `Attempts`, it is simply not being used because a value exists in `ModelState` with the `Attempts` key.

One way to fix this is to clear the value that's stored in `ModelState`, using something like this:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if (!IsCorrect())
    {
        ModelState.Remove(nameof(Attempts));
        Attempts++;
        return Page();
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

When a `ModelState` value doesn't exist, the value is read from the `Attempts` property on your `PageModel` implementation, as expected.