# input tag helper for ASP.NET Core doesn't change its text to the bound model field

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using the `input` tag helper for my Razor view like so:

```
<input type="text" asp-for="MsgFromFilter" id="txtMsgFromFilter" />
```

So this should be bound to my model's `MsgFromFilter` string field.  Although, when I submit the form, this field in my model is bound to the value in the textbox, it doesn't work the other way round: when I set the value of this field in my controller, the view doesn't set that as the default value of the text input element; it just maintains the last value submitted in that `input` field.  How can I get the text `input` to default its value on page load to the value in the model rather than the last value that was submitted in the `input`?

Comment: The context is different, but I think my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669863/change-bound-property-in-onpost-in-model-is-invalid/53675887#53675887) could help.

Comment: Try to call the Clear method at ModelState class: ModelState.Clear();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @KirkLarkin I discovered that to set the defaults for the `input` fields rendered by the Razor view, I need to set `ModelState`.  So in my controller I have to do two things, set `ModelState` and the model itself:

```
if (btnReset) {
    ModelState.Remove(nameof(model.MsgFromFilter));
    model.MsgFromFilter = null;
}
```

This works for resetting the value of that model field as well as the Razor view input element to blank.