# How is RazorPages (Core3.1) using asp-for with HTML input?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Why is asp-for not populating the input-value with server-side changes when using asp-for during a post-back?

If I use the asp-for without explicitly setting input[value] attribute my user input data is preserved but my server-side changes are ignored. Conversely if I explicitly set the input[value] attribute, my user input data is preserved and any server-side changes are honored during the round trip.

#### Steps to Reproduce

**Initial Page Load**

[image]

**User Input then Click "What the?"**

[image]

**Output from PostBack**

[image]

#### Sample Code

```html
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
  <p>
    Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.
  </p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
      <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" asp-for="NameWithoutValue" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" asp-for="NameWithValue" value="@Model.NameWithValue" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="WhatThe">What the?</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public void OnPostWhatThe()
    {
        NameWithoutValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        NameWithValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public string NameWithoutValue { get; set; } = "without-value-attribute";

    [BindProperty]
    public string NameWithValue { get; set; } = "with-value-attribute";
}
```

Comment: That's just how `asp-for` works: it uses the values entered by the user when provided.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669863/change-bound-property-in-onpost-in-model-is-invalid/53675887#53675887) should help explain that a little more.

Comment: Ah so the manual usage of input[value] overrides any auto-binding that was performed by asp-for and ModelState - per your link if I clear the ModelState it works as expected.